# Add more file types using parcel service worker cache plugin

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, workbox, parcel

I'm developing an open-source [pwa project](https://github.com/andredarcie/get-out-game) using parcel and [parcel-plugin-sw-cache](https://github.com/mischnic/parcel-plugin-sw-cache), to build an application that can run offline.

And add this code to *package.json* file

```
  "cache": {
    "disablePlugin": false,
    "inDev": true,
    "strategy": "default",
    "importWorkboxFrom": "local"
  },
```

Files like html, js and css are available offline but sounds in .wav or .mp3 format are not, how can I change this default setting to add sounds or other file types?

How to add other types of files to globPatterns and change the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin creator answered me in an [issue](https://github.com/mischnic/parcel-plugin-sw-cache/issues/31) in the repository, talking to add it to the cache object and it really worked.

Solution in `package.json` file:

```
  "cache": {
    "disablePlugin": false,
    "inDev": true,
    "strategy": "default",
    "importWorkboxFrom": "local",
    "globPatterns": [
      "**/*.{html,js,css,jpg,png,wav,mp3,mpeg,ttf}"
    ]
  },
```